# Pass data in vue from single parent component to child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue component that is page.vue.
And I have a child vue component that is card.vue as shown below.

I can't get it to work with injecting data into the card(child) component.

I tried injecting data inside  and 
in the data function for the page component.

Page.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <card></card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "../Card.vue"
export default {
    name: 'skills',
    components: {
      "card": Card
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            message: "Skills"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Card.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container drop-shadow">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'card',
    data: function() {
        return {
            data: "",
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want that card is reusable from other components also other than Page.vue. 
Need to inject data into card respective to where it is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that you can pass data down.

The first is through the use of [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

METHOD 1:

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <card :message="message"></card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "../Card.vue"
export default {
    name: 'skills',
    components: {
      "card": Card
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            message: "Skills"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This will make the data available in Card.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="container drop-shadow">{{ message }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'card',
    props: ['message'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            data: "",
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

METHOD 2:
You could also put a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#ad) in Card.vue which will allow you to put content in between the element tags on the parent like so.
Page.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <card>{{ message }}</card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "../Card.vue"
export default {
    name: 'skills',
    components: {
      "card": Card
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            message: "Skills"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Card.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="container drop-shadow">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'card',
    data: function() {
        return {
            data: "",
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work. But I can't get it to work with passing of an object. What am I missing?

Comment: You’ll have to be more specific

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by passing an object. Do you mean an actual ```javascript Object```? Why are you passing an object?